# Converting dto to entity saving strategy in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application with spring data-jpa we use hibernate implementation

when we have a Parent entity with a list of Child (one to many and cascade.all) and we use dto what is the strategy to saving?

We must loop on the child, compare with dto, if there are existing element, update value, if they are some new, add element, if some has been removed, remove it from the list?

Example

```
Parent parent = repo.findById(Integer id);

//remove items who dont exit anymore
Childs childs = bean.getChild();
for (Iterator<Childs> iterator = childs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    //compare with dto...

}


for (ChildsDto childsDto : ChildsDto) {

    if(childsDto==null){
        //add new element in the list of childs of parent
    }else{
        update element in the list of childs of parent
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long the *childsDto* contains the id you can make them to a list of *Childs* and then set the list to the *parent*.

e.g.:

```
List<Childs> childsFromDto = new ArrayList();
for (ChildsDto childsDto : ChildsDto) {

if(childsDto==null){
    //add new element in the list of childs of parent


    Childs child = new Childs();
    child.setId(childsDto.getId());
    ....
    childsFromDto.add(child);
}
parent.setChilds(childsFromDto);
```

By saving the *parent* the list will be merged as desired.

And if you want to delete the childs that don't have a parent anymore you can add orphanRemoval to the relation in *Parent* as followed:

`@OneToMany(mappedBy=..., orphanRemoval="true")
 Collection<Childs> childs;`

Comment: by "As long the childsDto contains the id you can make them to a list of Childs and then set the list to the parent. By saving the parent the list will be merged as desired." you mean take every id, do a query to the db, take the bean, update field...

Comment: i updated the answer and hope it's more clear what i meant

Answer (score 1):

You can have two basic ways of filtering out the duplicates from your `DTO` list.

**First way**

Iterate through your `DTO` list and *filter out* the duplicates

**Second way**

Make child composition as a `Set` in your `Parent` entity like so

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    ...

    @OneToMany
    Set<Child> children;

    ...

}
```

Now in your `Child` entity override `equals` and `hashcode` and define how your `Child` entity is unique. This will force the `Set` to ***NOT*** add duplicate `Child` to your `Parent` entity.

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    ...

    @OneToMany
    Set<Child> children;

    ...

}
```